# Interface: class without implementaion keyword

Tags: java

The below class Fruit uses the method peel of class interface without implementing it and also it is not an abstract class is it hiding the method?

```
interface Peelable {
    int peel();
}

class Fruit {
    // Return int number of pieces of peel that
    // resulted from the peeling activity.
    public int peel() {
        System.out.println("Peeling is appealing.");
        return 1;
    }
}

class Apple implements Peelable {
    private Fruit fruit = new Fruit();
    public int peel() {
        return fruit.peel();
    }
}

class FoodProcessor {
    static void peelAnItem(Peelable item) {
        item.peel();
    }
}

class Example5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Apple apple = new Apple();
        FoodProcessor.peelAnItem(apple);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I don't understand the question.  `Fruit` is a concrete class that doesn't `extend` or `implement` anything.  So what's the problem?

Comment: "Fruit uses the method peel of class interface" - no, it implements an unrelated method that just happens to have the same name! `Fruit` doesn't implement `Peelable` in your code.

Comment: Also, why does `Apple` have a `Fruit` as a field? Doesn't really make sense...

Answer (score 1):

`Fruit` has no relation(*) to `Peelable` or `Apple`, since it [`Fruit`] does not implement `Peelable`.

They are just two classes [`Apple`, `Fruit`] or class and interface [`Fruit`, `Peelable` which happen to have a method with the same name.

(*) No is-a relation to be more exact. Obviously, `Apple` has a `Fruit`, as a field.